# Facebook login problem in iphone?

Tags: iphone, authentication, facebook

In app I used fbconnect library in case of my app the fb browser shows lot of thing but i actually want the browser which shows only two textfield & one button for submit what i do for that still i'm using only fbconnect not fbconnect with json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to understand your question, to be honest. I will try my best to make the most appropriate guess

If you use FBConnect library, you have to use their login dialog, this is the common expected User Experience. Whenever users touch the button "F connect", they expect to see the FB connect dialog includes a lot of information and username and password textfield

Comment: I know dialog includes lots of information but i want actually this type of dialog with the help of fbconnect which will be appeared like this link http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk  plz download source through this link and tell what i do but still i'm using only fbconnect not fbconnect with json